# How do I summon a chicken zombie jockey with diamond armor using a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been working with command blocks for a while and I have gotten pretty good at them, however I'm trying to make a baby zombie (with full diamond armor) riding a chicken and I just can't do it! I can make a baby zombie riding a chicken, or a baby zombie wearing diamond armor, but I can't do both. Where should both qualities go in the coding?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/349279/185203), but not quite.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the `Riding:` attribute when you spawn it in. This will produce a zombie chicken jockey in full diamond armor, with a diamond sword (the first item):

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {IsBaby:1,Riding:{id:Chicken},Equipment:[{id:276},{id:310},{id:311},{id:312},{id:313}]}
```

It's *very* likely that you just need to add `Riding:{id:Chicken}` to what you've currently got in your command block, and adjust the coordinates to fit.

The decimal values for [armor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor) and [swords](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sword) (or other weapons, etc) can be substituted to fit whatever need.

*Editorial note - reader beware! It is extremely fun to do positively silly things with this and then realize you spent the whole day doing it.*

Comment: I totally agree w/ your last statement there, I remember when I first played minecraft, I started playing in the morning, looked up at the clock later, and it said 7:00 PM already.

Answer (score 1):

OP Zombie Villager Chicken Jockey Command:

```
/summon zombie_villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Your Worst Nightmare", CustomNameVisible:1,IsBaby:1,Equipment: [{id:diamond_sword,Count:1,tag: {ench:[{id:sharpness,lvl:10}]}}, {id:diamond_boots,Count:1,tag: {ench:[{id:protection,lvl:10}]}}, {id:diamond_leggings,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:protection,lvl:10}]}}, {id:diamond_chestplate,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:protection,lvl:10}]}}, {id:diamond_helmet,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:protection,lvl:10}]}}], Riding:{id:"Chicken",IsChickenJockey:1}}
```

Use this for good enchanted gear drops.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
/summon PigZombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:276},{id:310},{id:311},{id:312},{id:313}],CustomName:lol Zombie,Riding:{id:"Chicken"IsChickenJockey:1}}
```

Comment: Baby Zombie riding a Chicken, not a Zombie Pigmen.

Answer (score -1):

To summon a baby zombie with items, type this:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {IsBaby:1,CustomName:Equipped Baby Zombie,Equipment:{[id:297]}]
```

and bam, there you go.  Copy and paste this on your Minecraft server.

Comment: This answer does not add anything new to the question, or to existing answers. Also, like all code-related answers on StackOverflow, **please perhaps provide some explanation on how the code works**.

Answer (score -3):

I would use this:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Sittin' On The Chicken",
CustomNameVisible:1,IsBaby:1,Equipment:
[{id:diamond_sword,Count:1,tag:
{ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}},
{id:diamond_boots,Count:1,tag:
{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}},
{id:diamond_leggings,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}},
{id:diamond_chestplate,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}},
{id:diamond_helmet,Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}]}}],
Riding:{id:"Chicken",IsChickenJockey:1}}
```

[image]