# How do I summon multiple mobs riding eachother?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that I can use `/summon` to spawn multiple mobs using

```
/summon <entity> x y z {Riding:{id:Item,Age:6000,Item:{id:1},Ri­ding:{id:Zombie}}}
```

But I want to know how I can use that to spawn jockeys.
For example how would I use that if I wanted to spawn Baby Zombies riding Chickens.

If you want to see the site click [Here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/350423-multi-summon-summon-multiple-entities-blocks-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

`/summon Chicken x y z {Riding:{id:Zombie,IsBaby:1}}`

The theory is to delete `id:Item,Age:6000,Item:{id:1}`.

Comment: How to I use the multi-spawn trick using this?

Comment: You can just add `,Riding:{id:Zombie,IsBaby:1` tag after each `{IsBaby:1`. Remember to put one `}` for each `Riding:`

Comment: So if I wanted to spawn 2 I would use /summon x y z Chicken {Riding:{id:Zombie,isBaby:1},Riding:{id:Zombie,isBaby:1}}

Comment: Uh, no. It would be: `/summon x y z Chicken {Riding:{id:Zombie,IsBaby:1,Riding:{id:Zombie,IsBaby:1}}}` As you add `,Riding:{id:Zombie,IsBaby:1` after each `IsBaby:1`

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [How do I summon a chicken zombie jockey with diamond armor using a command block?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167492/how-do-i-summon-a-chicken-zombie-jockey-with-diamond-armor-using-a-command-block), you can use the command:

> /summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {IsBaby:1,Riding:{id:Chicken},Equipment:[{id:276},{id:310},{id:311},{id:312},{id:313}]}

...to summon a baby zombie riding a chicken. If you want to spawn a different kind of jockey such as a skeleton-spider jockey, all you have to do is use the command:

> /summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:Spider},Equipment:[{id:261}]}

This summons a Skeleton riding a Spider, holding a bow (see {id:261}, which is the decimal value for a bow.).

Comment: How to I use the multi-spawn trick using this?